# How to make a Navigation bar transparent and fade out like in the photo app in the iPhone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

i am new to iPhone Programming ...can anybody help me out please..

i want to develop an app like photo app in iPhone..

How to make the naveigation bar and toolbar transparent and fadeout like in photo app in iPhone

Thank u ..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`UINavigationBar` inherits from `UIView`, so you can use `UIView`'s animation methods to fade it out by setting the `alpha` property to 0. This should work:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[navigationBar setAlpha:0.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 12):

Since I'm a block-using kinda guy, I use this little snippet.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    [navigationBar setAlpha:0.0];
}];
```

Feels nicer to me, but you should probably only do this if you're used to blocks and you're rockin' iOS 4.0 or later.

Answer (score 6):

To make the bar transparent, using `setBarStyle:` using the `UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent`.

To hide the bar with fade animation, use the code snippet Macatomy posted.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple specs, you should never change the `frame`, `bounds`, or `alpha` values of the navigation bar.

To hide (or show) the navigation bar, you can change the `navigationBarHidden` property or call the `setNavigationBarHidden:animated` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, using `-[UINavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:animated:]` always performs slide-out effect instead of the fade-out effect that the OP requested.