# How to make tableview's content displayed under a transparent navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

How to make tableview's content displayed under a transparent navigation bar?

Like this:In "Photos" app, albums displayed under navigation bar.

Special thanks

[image]

Comment: also take custom navigationbar , its very easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use _rootNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent; then set correct tableview frame thats it. If you are in xib dont forget to simulate the translucent navigation bar.

Comment: I make this, but something going wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946361/how-ios-uitableview-under-navigationbar Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

One way I have found to accomplish this is by shifting your tableview's superview up to have the origin at {0, 0}.  However after researching more several people have said altering the superview (UIViewControllerWrapperView) is a bad idea.  However I also have not found any information on why just changing the frame would create problems. I am shifting the superview right now and haven't found any problems related to it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you can set it like this:

```
[navigationBar setAlpha:0.5f];
```

Comment: I already use         _rootNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent; but what i want to know is how to make tableview taller by 44px.

Answer (score 0):

For making the navigation bar transparent alone, you can check this post, [How to make a Navigation bar transparent and fade out like in the photo app in the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106025/how-to-make-a-navigation-bar-transparent-and-fade-out-like-in-the-photo-app-in-t)

Also check this [How to set the transparency color for Toolbar and Navigation bar using MonoTouch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593761/how-to-set-the-transparency-color-for-toolbar-and-navigation-bar-using-monotouch)

I am not sure whether you can add the table view behind the navigation bar. You might have to add it as a subview of `self.parentViewController.view`.

Another way to do this is by hiding navigation bar and using a transparent tool bar in place of that. This can be added on top of the current view. The only problem is with the back button. You might have to use custom button for that.