# How iOS UITableView under NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have set

```
NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = true;
```

Then add table and set frame to RootView Frame, and:

```
    public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
            float y = this.TopLayoutGuide.Length;
            table.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets (y, 0, 0, 0);
        }
```

But, I Have table Scroll Bar under NavigationBar *(I use monotouch):*

[image]

Comment: Look at here **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159621/converting-ios-6-app-to-ios-7/19159882#19159882**

Comment: Unfortunately no, I can't find it in Monotouch. And already ExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES, EdgesForExtendedLayout = ALL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved task with this simple code:

```
table.ScrollIndicatorInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(64, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Hardcoding the size is a bad idea.

Answer (score 31):

Just put

`navigationBar.translucent = NO;` you problem will solve :)

Other option is,,

Put following code.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeBottom];
}
```

Another option is ..

[Why does UIViewController extend under UINavigationBar, while UITableViewController doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143353/why-does-uiviewcontroller-extend-under-uinavigationbar-while-uitableviewcontrol)

Comment: I have already EdgesForExtendedLayout = ALL; And AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is already set to TRUE

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
    if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    {
       self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
       self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    }
```

Comment: I already found solution. table.ScrollIndicatorInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(64, 0, 0, 0); or this method is wrong?

Comment: I think your method is only suitable for uiscrollview or uitableview not uiview.

Answer (score 2):

Solutions that introduce a magic constant don't scale most of the time. For example, if the next iPhone introduces a different navigation bar height we'll have to update our code.

Fortunately, Apple provided us cleaner ways of overcoming this issue, for example [topLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide):

> The topLayoutGuide property comes into play when a view controller is
> frontmost onscreen. It indicates the highest vertical extent for
> content that you don't want to appear behind a translucent or
> transparent UIKit bar (such as a status or navigation bar)

Programmatically you can achieve with the following code snippet (the same can be achieved via IB too):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
  tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
       topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
  ])
}
```

**Note:** topLayoutGuide is deprecated on iOS 11, we should use the [safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide) property of UIView instead.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
let yOffset = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(yOffset, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Hard coding this is definitely a bad idea. If you would have used this pre-iPhone X times, it would be broken on an iPhone X by default.

Comment: @Lapidus I changed the code as you suggested, well now it will work properly.

Comment: yOffset return 88 in iPhone 11 iOS 13. Big gap at top.. not working