# Getting navigation bar height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I call a `UIViewController` by clicking `UITabBarController`'s item.  When I try to get navigation bar's height in `UIViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method like below:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
```

both above lines return zero. How could I get navigation bar's height?

Comment: what is the root view controller? Tab bar or navigation bar?

Comment: Is self.navigationController != nil in your viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you haven't missed any of the following lines of code

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];

self.window.rootViewController = myNavigationController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
 CGFloat navigationBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height;
```

Answer (score -1):

Note that it behaves differently if you set:

```
navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

[More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946361/how-ios-uitableview-under-navigationbar)

Comment: This does not answer the question - it should be a comment on the original question.

Comment: You should have waited a couple more years to tell me that